# How to add a dll file to Oracle Apex project?

Tags: c#, oracle, dll, oracle-apex

I need to add a dll file to my APEX application.
This is a school project, and the dll can be anything, so I would like to know the easiest way to do this.

I'm using online Oracle APEX at https://apex.oracle.com
I'm not sure if I can upload a dll directly there or I need to find another solution.

I think my dll would just count the number of records in a database or something simply as this.

Comment: The architecture you're describing doesn't make a lot of sense.  If you have access to an Oracle database running on a Windows machine (apex.oracle.com does not qualify), I suppose you could install a DLL on that database server and create an external procedure in the database that uses the DLL and then call that external procedure from APEX.  That would be a very, very unusual architecture, though, and it would be strange to describe that as "adding a DLL to an APEX application" so I'm not at all sure that is what you're really being asked to do.

Comment: I was just asked to use a C# dll inside my project. I'm not sure either what to do.

Comment: If you have a school assignment that isn't clear, I'd strongly suggest that you talk to the professor to figure out what you're really being asked to do.  Unless there is some Windows machine with Oracle installed that you have full access to, and unless you've discussed external procedures in Oracle in your class, I don't understand what you've been asked to do either.

Comment: It is possible to create .Net stored procedures in an Oracle database but this would require far more access to the database than you will get using apex.oracle.com. It also has to be a Windows server for this to work.

Comment: The Oracle database has a huge amount of built-in functionality (counting records is really really basic functionality) and you don't need to add external resources to do this.

Comment: And a calculator can do a lot of things, but you still need to learn how to multiply. Anyways, my homework was approved without including the dll.